# Trying to rearrange simple expressions, I would appreciate any help.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have managed to derive the following correct expressions for variables $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$:

**(i)** $x_{1}=\left(\frac{p \ x_{2}^\frac{1}{4}}{2w_{1}} \right)^{2}$

**(ii)** $x_{2}=\left(\frac{p \ x_{1}^\frac{1}{2}}{4w_{2}} \right)^\frac{4}{3}$

I would like to rearrange **(i)** such that $x_{2}$ is no longer required in the expression. I would also like to do the same for **(ii)** with respect to $x_{1}$

In the case of $(ii)$, the obvious method would be to substitute **(i)** into **(ii)**

This yields:

$$x_{2}=\left(\frac{p \ A^\frac{1}{2}}{4w_{2}} \right)^\frac{4}{3}$$

$$where \ A =\left(\frac{p \ x_{2}^\frac{1}{4}}{2w_{1}} \right)^{2}$$

After substitution, the result should be:

$ x_{2} = \left(\frac{p^{4}}{2^{6} w_{2}^{2} w_{1}^{2}} \right)$

However, I just can't seem to successfully substitute **(i)** into **(ii)**. I fear that I might be over complicating the process, could anyone help?

Comment: I would use WolframAlpha for something like this. Letting $x = x_1$, here's the output: [Click here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x+%3D+%28p*%28p*x%5E%281%2F2%29%2F%284*w_2%29%29%5E%281%2F4%29%2F%282*w_1%29%29%5E2+for+x)

Comment: And here's the output from letting $y = x_2$: [Click here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y+%3D+%28p*%28p*y%5E%281%2F4%29%2F%282*w_1%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2F%284*w_2%29%29%5E%284%2F3%29+for+y)

Comment: @Clarinetist Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x_1$

$x_{1}=\left(\frac{p \ x_{2}^\frac{1}{4}}{2w_{1}} \right)^{2} = \left(\frac{p \ }{2w_{1}} \right)^{2} x_{2}^\frac{1}{2}$

$x_1 = \left(\frac{p \ }{2w_{1}} \right)^{2}  \left(\left(\frac{p \ }{4w_{2}} \right)^\frac{4}{3} x_{1}^\frac{2}{3}\right)^\frac{1}{2}$

$x_1^2 = \left(\frac{p \ }{2w_{1}} \right)^{4} \left(\frac{p \ }{4w_{2}} \right)^\frac{4}{3} x_{1}^\frac{2}{3}$

$x_1^\frac{4}{3} = \left(\frac{p \ }{2w_{1}} \right)^{4} \left(\frac{p \ }{4w_{2}} \right)^\frac{4}{3}$

$x_1= \left(\frac{p \ }{2w_{1}} \right)^{3} \left(\frac{p}{4w_{2}} \right)$ = $p^4 \left(\frac{1 \ }{2w_{1}} \right)^{3} \left(\frac{1}{4w_{2}} \right)$

$$\mathcal{x_1=\frac{p^4}{2^5 w_1^{3} w_2}}$$

You can use the same method to obtain an expression for $x_2$.